# Aligning Clusters within Graphviz

Tags: graphviz

I am using Graphviz to automatically create an architecture diagram.  I am having the following two problems and was hoping to get assistance.

1. I am using UUID to uniquely identify a component (example: `"a5320de8-a320-11ea-bb37-0242ac130002" [label="Component A"]`).  When mapping A -> B, I'll get "Component A" -> b0c5e47c.  Which is strange.  The only way that I've been able to map UUID to UUID is to put quotes around them. Any suggestions?
2. I want to align clusters in a specific manner and specific direction. I've tried `{rank=same; cluster_B, cluster_C, cluster_D};` and `"9653369c-a322-11ea-bb37-0242ac130002" -> "aa31adb9-9621-40c2-855c-621832dd8c61" [style=invis]` But neither work.

I have three sections within my dot file, they are:

- Components (within this section, I list out all 100+ components and color code them based on a specific rule.
- Clusters (within this section, I cluster the components into specific 'groupings')
- Diagram or mapping (within this section, I then map the different components and clusters).

Here is a sample of my DOT file.

```
digraph architecture {
    #graph [rankdir=LR]
    compound=true;

    #Compliant
    node[fillcolor="#013220" style="filled" shape=square fontcolor="white"];
        "a5320de8-a320-11ea-bb37-0242ac130002" [label="Component A"]
        "b0c5e47c-a320-11ea-bb37-0242ac130002" [label="Component B"]

     #Clusters
        #Customer-facing client application cluster
        subgraph cluster_A{
            label="Client Apps";

        "f7b3915d-6b3d-4d4c-bef0-bdabda915c03"; 
        "9912de2b-739a-4c5c-834e-e0c3d09d70d1";
        "16bb2066-9293-470e-99ec-c59d8426c0ab";
        "641a6601-f4f6-4c06-baa6-e5e232f8abed";
        "c5e92b09-a470-4fb6-af5c-e5f7dbeff919";
        }

     #Diagrams
     "f7b3915d-6b3d-4d4c-bef0-bdabda915c03" -> {"35305026-d285-458c-85ad-7eae4e785e84", "76e0e679-42a6-47f0-9164-abc223da07fe"}; 
      76e0e679-42a6-47f0-9164-abc223da07fe" -> "35305026-d285-458c-85ad-7eae4e785108";
}
```

I get something like:
[image]

However, I want to arrange the cluster is a specific way, like:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As you found out, hyphens are not legal characters in a node ID unless the string is quoted.  If you want more info:  https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html
2. There is no straight-forward to align clusters.  Sometime you can force desired alignment by embedding multiple clusters within another cluster to "shrink-wrap" them.  For example embed B3 and B4 within cluster B34.  But no guarantees.

You can use **gvpr** to reposition clusters (and their contents) but that can get pretty complex.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback sroush. Is there a 'better' solution for dynamically creating an architecture diagram? Basically, I have a JSON file with a list of components and I want to visualize it in a diagram format.  Any suggestions? Thanks again for the help.